# Gulp minify CSS delete expression

Tags: sass, gulp, minify

The following line from my icomoon font scss will be deleted by gulp 'minify-css' task

```
.icon-home {
    *zoom: expression(this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '&#xe900;');
}
```

how to avoid deleting the ie expression fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the expression, is the "*". Try removing it:

```
.icon-home {
    zoom: expression(this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '&#xe900;');
}
```

I think it's not a solution, you can try the `compatibility` option of gulp-minify-css and set it to IE7 for example.